# 'NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined' even though it is imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I keep on getting the error `NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined` when running this script.

I've tried importing `subprocess` inside the `__init__` function of the `ProgramBody` class, but that did not do anything to change the error. I've also tried to use `from subprocess import check_output` but that would just give me the same `NameError` but with `check_output` instead of `subprocess`.

I put the `import` inside of the function `get_speed` and `set_speed` functions at one point out of desperation, and it worked; but a solution such as that is very unfeasible as those functions will be called ~4 times a second.

**Code**

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading

class ProgramBody():
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_speed = 0
        self.current_temp = 0
        self.update = True
        self.change = True
        self.update_wait = 0.25

    def get_speed (self):
        return subprocess.check_output (["nvidia-settings", "-tq", "[fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed"])
    def set_speed (self, speed):
        subprocess.call (["nvidia-settings", "-a", "[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1", "-a", "[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=" + str(speed)])
    def get_temp (self):
        return subprocess.check_output (["nvidia-settings", "-tq", "[gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp"])

    def const_update(self):
        while self.update:
            self.current_speed = self.get_speed ()
            self.current_temp = self.get_temp ()
            time.sleep (self.update_wait)

class ThreadingExample(object):
    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):
        body.const_update()


body = ProgramBody()
thread = ThreadingExample()
```

**Stacktrace**

```
(Pdb) Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "FanSpeed.py", line 42, in run
    body.const_update()
  File "FanSpeed.py", line 32, in const_update
    self.current_temp = self.get_temp ()
  File "FanSpeed.py", line 27, in get_temp
    return subprocess.check_output (["nvidia-settings", "-tq", "[gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp"])
NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

Python 2.7.10

Comment: which version of python ?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that, I'm using Python 2.7.10

Comment: Well, subprocess was introduced in 2.4, so wasnt sure about the version. Also, can you please edit the question with the exact stacktrace?

Comment: Can do, sorry about that. I find it odd that even though I'm calling `get_speed` first, the error arises in `get_temp` even though both use `subprocess`.

Comment: This is very weird.. I think the threads are not importing the import statements as expected.. Can you just disable threading and see if it really works ?

Comment: I commented out the `ThreadingExample` function and it's call later on in the code, then I called the `const_update` function in the `ProgramBody` class with a `print` statement in it and it worked completely normally. I guess there's something up with the threading as you said. If there is an alternative to using threads to allow this `while` loop to run in the background that would be great.

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down to it being if I call the `const_update` function from the `run` function it will cause this error. Otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have a method to join the thread after it starts or finishes.

I do however get an exception

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

This is because we need to tell subprocess where to find the executable nvidia-settings.

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading

class ProgramBody():
    def __init__(self):
    self.current_speed = 0
    self.current_temp = 0
    self.update = True
    self.change = True
    self.update_wait = 0.25

    def get_speed (self):
        return subprocess.check_output (["nvidia-settings", "-tq", "[fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed"])
    def set_speed (self, speed):
        subprocess.call (["nvidia-settings", "-a", "[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1", "-a", "[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=" + str(speed)])
    def get_temp (self):
        return subprocess.check_output (["nvidia-settings", "-tq", "[gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp"])

    def const_update(self):
        while self.update:
            self.current_speed = self.get_speed ()
            self.current_temp = self.get_temp ()
            time.sleep (self.update_wait)

class ThreadingExample():
    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def run(self):
        body.const_update()

    def stop(self):
        self.thread.join()


body = ProgramBody()
thread = ThreadingExample()
thread.stop()
```

I have modified the processes to be ['ls', '-lah'] and added before time.sleep the following and it works appropriately.

```
print self.current_speed
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Additionally the you should not be defining body as a global variable. Instantiate the ProgramBody class within the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found out that any commands after the `thread.stop()` aren't executed, placing them before it works as normal, and removing it altogether doesn't seem to have any side effects, can you explain please?

Comment: The thread.stop is there so that the script has an endpoint. You need a method on your thread class that checks if the thread has ended and if it has, it calls thread stop.

`if thread.has_ended(): thread.stop()`

If you ctrl-c/z the script. It needs a way of joining all the threads for garbage collection. Otherwise you can end up with zombie processes.

Additionally the join method on a thread kills that thread. This is why ProgramBody should be instantiated inside your thread. That way it cleans up after itself.